# Protect PDF from editing after convert from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba

Below is the VBA code for converting an Excel file to PDF with the required name of the file. How can I modify this macro to protect the PDF from being edited?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'saves the file as PDF and adds a date parameter to the name of the file

aux1 = ""
If Month(Date) < 10 Then
aux1 = "0"
End If
aux2 = ""
If Day(Date) < 10 Then
aux2 = "0"
End If

fileN = "Salary Slip of " & Workbooks.Application.Sheets("Salary Slip").Cells(10, 5).Value
fileD = Format(Sheets("Salary Slip").Cells(6, 2).Value, "mmm-yy")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileN & " for " & fileD & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Using only Excel VBA objects you won't be able to protect it. You need to install another tool too (Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Distiller, pdf printer ...) which support this functionality, and use their .dll-s in your code. I've never done it, so can't really help more:(

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment, there is no direct way to achieve this without external tools. A full-blown PDF library would be needed which is probably too big and complex to incorporate into an Excel file.

To prevent `PDF` changes, you could use tools like [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to encrypt the file and limit the permissions. You can call `PDFtk` from VBA using the [Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx) function. Use `pdftk --help` to get to know all options.

**Example:**

```
call Shell("pdftk.exe myfile.pdf output protected.pdf encrypt_128bit")
```

The example assumes that pdftk.exe can be found along the search `PATH`. Add double quotes in case your file paths contain spaces.

`PDFtk` disallows printing encrypted files, unless it is allowed explicitely.
Otherwise, it would be fairly easy to circumvent such a restriction using the [print to file trick](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-circumvent-pdf-editing-security/).